# my SO reputation has gone down 19 points — why?

Tags: support, reputation

Why has my reputation gone down by 19 points?

i find nothing in the envelop link

my reputation is  down from 984 to 965 19 points down....

Comment: Did you know you can click on the little envelope at the top of the screen by your login name?  Then click the reputation tab and look at the different time periods to see where your reputation has been changing.

Comment: @GreenMatt - it won't show reputation lost as a result of answers being unaccepted or votes being withdrawn, though there's only a small window for the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A question you answered with upvotes may have been deleted, and when your rep was recalculated it went down. See [Why did reputation go down by 45 points?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42658/154388)

Comment: how to recalculate?

Comment: @moon - click the `Trigger Reputation Recalc` button at the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/reputation.  Be aware that your reputation usually goes down as a result of this unless you have a lot of answers/questions with downvotes that you've deleted.

Comment: @tvanfosson thanx it works